# C# how to dynamically cast object

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

```
public class TriggerableObject 
{
    Trigger(){
        DoSomething();
    }
}
public class X : TriggerableObject
{
    Trigger(){
        DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
public class X2 : TriggerableObject
{
    Trigger(){
        DoSomethingOther();
    }
}
public class Trigger
{
    TriggerableObject obj = FindMyObject();
    obj.Trigger();
}
```

Class Trigger finds class X from other object, but when it calls Trigger(), the method from base class is called (`DoSomething()`). However, I want it to call Trigger from class X (`DoSomethingElse()`), which works if I cast it as class X. The problem is that I don't know if the found class will be X or X2, so if I statically cast it to X, then it won't work with X2.
How do I make this work?

Comment: Make Trigger a virtual method and override it in X and X2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to override that behavior in the base class.  You need to first mark your method in the base class as virtual, and then override that function in all the classes that inherit from the base class.

```
public class TriggerableObject 
{
    public virtual Trigger(){
        DoSomething();
    }
}
public class X : TriggerableObject
{
    public override Trigger(){
        DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
public class X2 : TriggerableObject
{
    public override Trigger(){
        DoSomethingOther();
    }
}
public class Trigger
{
    TriggerableObject obj = FindMyObject();
    obj.Trigger();
}
```

Note that if you did not want to have an implementation in the base class, you could use an abstract method

Comment: Thank you very much, the interface also works, but this way i can keep the inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

**Interfaces** are your friend. If you have a particular structure (as you have) in your code but the implementation is different then think **interfaces**. Of course this isn't always the answer but your above sample could be written the following way.

```
public interface ITriggerableObject 
{
    Trigger();
}
public class X : ITriggerableObject 
{
    Trigger(){
        DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
public class X2 : ITriggerableObject 
{
    Trigger(){
        DoSomethingOther();
    }
}
public class Trigger
{
    ITriggerableObject obj = FindMyObject();
    obj.Trigger();
}
```

Syntax might be off since I did not compile it but semantics are solid.

[.NET Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e2e18x.aspx)